Why doesn't SQLAlchemy recognize type JSON for this column?
Using SQLAlchemy to interact with Google BigQuery in Python to manage tables that contain JSON fields I get warnings about unrecognized JSON types.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry

registry.register('bigquery', 'sqlalchemy_bigquery', 'BigQueryDialect')

The warning I get:

\sqlalchemy_bigquery_types.py:101: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'JSON' of column 'ExternalLinks'

How can I avoid these warnings? Is there a better approach?

https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy/issues/399#issuecomment-1729327447
